# Whenever I try to use my class, I get an error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that generates insults using a premade list. When I try to change the value of something from the classes mStart, mMid, or mEnd, I get an error. What am I doing wrong? I am new to coding so please inform me if I'm making a silly error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace albertisnultsim
{
class Program
{
    public class startSent
    {
        public string[] listofstarters = new string[10];
    }

    public  class middle
    {
        public string[] listofmiddles = new string[10];
    }

    public class end
    {
        public string[] listofends = new string[10];
    }

    startSent mstart = new startSent();
    middle mMid = new middle();
    end mEnd = new end();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the specific error?

Comment: *it gives me an error* is not a problem description unless you include the exact error message you're seeing. It's on the screen right in front of you, so there is no reason for you not to provide that information in your question.

Comment: @preciousbetine [You absolutely can.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)

Comment: Please show the code when you're "changing value of something" in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instances of the classes must be created in some specific scope other than just the namespace. Since all three classes have the same effective attributes, you can also use that fact to greatly simplify your code:

```
class Program
{
    public class Section
    {
        public string[] items = new string[10];
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Section start = new Section();
        Section middle = new Section();
        Section end = new Section();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want i think:

```
namespace albertisnultsim
{
    class Program
    {
        public class startSent
        {
            public string[] listofstarters = new string[10];

        }

        public class middle
        {
            public string[] listofmiddles = new string[10];

        }
        public class end
        {
            public string[] listofends = new string[10];

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            startSent mstart = new startSent();
            middle mMid = new middle();
            end mEnd = new end();

            mstart.listofstarters = new string[]{"setting1","1","setting2","apple"};
            Console.WriteLine(mstart.listofstarters[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank everyone who pointed out my mistakes. I really appreciate your feedback. Thank you.